# Get a coordinate system from raster file

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, loop

I am writing a code to loop through all the files in a folder and reproject them, using a raster as the spatial reference. I have a suspicion that there is a different way to get the coordinate system from a raster. This is my code so far:

```
#Import system modules
import arcpy
import os

#Set environment
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Project/Joined"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Get list of files in Joined folder
fileList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
print fileList

#Set raster as basis for coordinate system
base = "D:/Project/Data/Development.tif"
base2 = arcpy.Describe(base)
out_coor_system = arcpy.SpatialReference(base2)

#Loop through shapefiles in fileList and reproject 
for fc in fileList:
    outName = fc + '_rprj.shp'
    new = arcpy.Project_management(fc, outName, out_coor_system)
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
File "D:/Project/Data/Reproject.py", line 16, in <module>
    out_coor_system = arcpy.SpatialReference(base2)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 949, in __init__
    self._arc_object.createFromFile(item)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
```

From what I've read, this is a pretty generic error for Python IDLE to throw.

I made the code print out `out_coor_system` and I am getting: `<geoprocessing spatial reference object object at 0x0D2CE830>` printed out to me. Could this be the problem?

I also wanted to add that the projection I am trying to use is a custom one that my organization uses. I don't know if that's relevant (it seems it shouldn't be) but I wanted to throw that in.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Your code looks OK and I am not sure there is another, except if you look for a solution without arcpy. Could you explain what you have in mind ? On the other hand, **I would be very cautious with this kind of code** because you do not handle the datum transform, which could cause a systematic error (5 to 100 m) if your projections are based on different datums.

Comment: @radouxju -- I'm not sure I have anything in mind, however I did see some GDAL modules referenced in other answers about rasters so I thought there was maybe something there. I also don't think there is a datum transformation needed, according to the documentation if it is required, the error will say so. I'll add the error I'm getting from this code to the question, it might help illuminate the problem.

Comment: No, that is a generic error that *ESRI* throws. I've seen the same in ArcMap and the same in ArcObjects. It is *highly unusual* in Python code that doesn't involve ESRI. (Python is generally *much, much* better at giving useful information in errors.) Also, IDLE is just an editor. when you run a script, the engine that runs it would just be called "Python."

Comment: Also, `<geoprocessing spatial reference object object at 0x0D2CE830>` is just because ESRI failed to define a good `repr` (the function on Python objects that is called to get a string when the object is fed into `print`). All it means that there is a non-`None` object there; it could have any data. You would have to examine the *attributes* of that object to learn more about its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who helped me with this. I ended up creating a spatial reference object from the raster. What eventually worked was this:

```
#Set raster as basis for coordinate system
base = "D:/Project/Data/Development.tif"
sr = arcpy.CreateSpatialReference_management("", base)   

#Loop through shapefiles in fileList and reproject 
for fc in fileList:
    outName = fc[:-4] + '_rprj.shp'
    new = arcpy.Project_management(fc, outName, sr)
```

To be honest, I'm not sure why this worked. If anyone has any insight to offer, that would be great.

Comment: I don't see why the solution's suggested above didn't work for you. Your solution is also a different approach to the problem, you created a projection by copying it from a an existing raster. Where as the `x = arcpy.Describe (base).spatialReference` saves the projection from the given raster under the variable x. I believe both should work. Did it give you error when you tried @Emil's code?

Comment: It was the same error I had been getting. Would it have had anything to do with the projection being custom?

Answer (score 4):

You're codes not quite right. You're trying to create a `spatial reference` object from a `describe` object. Here's a fix:

```
#Set raster as basis for coordinate system
base = "D:/Project/Data/Development.tif"
out_coor_system = arcpy.Describe (base).spatialReference

#Loop through shapefiles in fileList and reproject 
for fc in fileList:
    outName = fc + '_rprj.shp'
    new = arcpy.Project_management (fc, outName, out_coor_system)
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
out_coor_system = arcpy.Describe(base).spatialReference
```

Answer (score 2):

if the `out_coor_system` is giving you an object, wouldn't you need to specify something like `out_coor_system.name`? because projections are specified by giving the projection name in the `arc.Project_management` args.I don't think the function is able to evaluate the object as it stands now.

Comment: Interesting idea. I tried it and got this error: ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Project). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000628: Cannot set input into parameter out_coor_system.

Comment: Ah! I guess the `.name` wasn't the right subscription. As per @freshhmints &  @Emil Brundage answer below. It looks like the `.spatialReference` singles out the name of the spatialReference from the raster describe object.